# How to make a RadioGroup scrollable in Android?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-radiogroup

I have a simple layout wherein there is a TextView, followed by a RadioGroup followed by another TextView (and finally an Admob adview). I am trying to make the RadioGroup scrollable and for the life of me, I cannot seem to make it do that. Please advise. My xml code is attached.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_statement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="@string/wait"        
    android:textSize="18sp" 
     />

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_choices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/textview_statement"       
    >

<RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/choices" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"     
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/choice1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choice" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/choice2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choice" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/choice3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choice" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/choice4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choice" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/dontknow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="@string/choice"
    android:checked="true" />

</RadioGroup>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/actonchoice_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_above="@+id/adViewQ"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:text="@string/actonchoice" 
    android:onClick="actOnChoice" 
    android:textSize="12sp"
 />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@id/adViewQ"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId=""
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" 
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Since you already have the `RadioGroup` wrapped in a `ScrollView`, what specifically is the problem?

Comment: Hi there. The problem is that whenever the first textview (textview_statement) has a lot of text, one or more radio buttons in the radiogroup are hidden by the button (actonchoice_button). And if I try to scroll, nothing happens. The choices remain hidden by the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that whenever the first textview (textview_statement) has a lot of text, one or more radio buttons in the radiogroup are hidden by the button (actonchoice_button). And if I try to scroll, nothing happens. The choices remain hidden by the button.

Add `android:layout_above="@+id/actonchoice_button"` to your `ScrollView`, to say that you want it to have its bottom edge anchored to the top of your `Button`. Then, the `ScrollView`, and its `RadioGroup`, will not go under the `Button`.

Comment: CommonsWare, thank you very much. Worked perfectly and I think I understand why!